# Write an update query where ID is X, and name is either foo or bar in zf

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I'd like to write the following SQL update query with Zend Framework:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_field
WHERE name = 'John'
AND (other_field = 'foo' OR other_field = 'bar')
```

How to do this with Zend Framework?

Comment: which adapter you use? zend-db? doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Model file for my_table ..if not create one inside your model directory.

```
 <?php  

  class Yournamespace_Model_Mytable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

            protected $_name = "my_table";
        public function updateFunction(){
           $data = array('my_field' => 'new value to be set');
           $where[] = 'name = John';
           $where[] = '(other_field = "foo" OR other_field = "bar")';       
                $update= $this->update($data, $where);        

        }

        }
```

just call in any action like this

```
$obj = new Yournamespace_Model_Mytable();
$obj->updateFunction();
```